# Delay Application While Data Loads From Database

Tags: java, android, events, fragment, blocking

i have a problem, i need to load the data of the user and present his details on the screen
im using a fragment inside activity and when i want to print the details in the fragment it calls a null exception

now the reason i assume causing the problem is-
the data still loads and when the fragment wants to print the data teh variable still points to NULL.

so my question , what should i do,
1.block the app untill the data loads ?
2.make an event ?

and most importantly how ?

ty!!

edit: this is the loading data + initializing the viewpager that displays the fragments ,it loads 1 the curr user into a static field in DataHelper class, all goes in the onCreate() method:

```
firebaseRef = new Firebase(ReferenceUrl.FIREBASE_CHAT_URL);
    mAuthStateListener=new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
            if(authData!=null)
            {
                firebaseRef.child(ReferenceUrl.CHILD_USERS).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(DataHelper.currUid)) {
                            DataHelper.currUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                LoadLogInActivity();
            }
        }
    };
    firebaseRef.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);

    //init viewpager and tabs for layout
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

the setupviewpager method:

```
  private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(FeedFragment.newInstance());
    adapter.addFragment(ChatFragment.newInstance());
    adapter.addFragment(SettingsFragment.newInstance());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

this is the onCreateView in the fragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_layout,container,false);

    TextView t = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    t.setText(DataHelper.currUser.getLastName());

    return view;
}
```

and the line that gives null:

```
t.setText(DataHelper.currUser.getLastName());
```

Comment: how much data you load from database.?

Comment: it depends on the sum of the users in the database , at this point just for trying i added 2 users, every user has 4 string vars

Comment: please post some code for database operations and load data into fragments.

Comment: I think in this scenario it is better to create callback method using interface, once data is received you can call that callback method inside you can bind the data to view.

Comment: can you give me an example how to do it plz ?